# ggplot of raster maps: Horizontal / vertical grid cells distortion

Tags: r, ggplot2, spatial, r-raster, tidyterra

I am plotting multiple projected raster objects (SpatRaster or raster stack; equal area projection; `EPSG:3035`), all having the same extent. [Example map](https://github.com/dieghernan/tidyterra/files/13322139/ExampleMap.zip)

However, the mapped grid cells are distorted, either horizontally or vertically (i.e. not square), or shown larger than they should be.

```
# vertically distorted  
ggplot2::ggplot() +
    tidyterra::geom_spatraster(data = terra::rast(ExampleMap[[1]])) +
    paletteer::scale_fill_paletteer_c(na.value = NA, "viridis::plasma")
```

[image]

```
# horizontally distorted  
ggplot2::ggplot() +
    tidyterra::geom_spatraster(data = terra::rast(ExampleMap[[2]])) +
    paletteer::scale_fill_paletteer_c(na.value = NA, "viridis::plasma")
```

[image]

---

Here is a full script for plotting one layer using different geoms:

```
require(raster)
require(stara)
require(ggplot2)

ExampleMap2 <- ExampleMap[[1]] %>% trim()
```

Using `geom_stars`

```
ggplot2::ggplot() +
  stars::geom_stars(data = stars::st_as_stars(ExampleMap2)) + 
  ggplot2::coord_equal() +
  ggplot2::theme_void() +
  ggplot2::scale_fill_continuous(na.value = NA) + 
  guides(fill = guide_legend(NULL)) +
  theme(aspect.ratio = 1) + 
  labs(title = "stars::geom_stars")
```

[image]

Using `tidyterra::geom_spatraster`

```
ggplot2::ggplot() +
  tidyterra::geom_spatraster(data = terra::rast(ExampleMap2)) + 
  ggplot2::theme_void() + 
  ggplot2::scale_fill_continuous(na.value = NA) + 
  guides(fill = guide_legend(NULL)) +
  theme(aspect.ratio = 1) + 
  labs(title = "tidyterra::geom_spatraster")
```

[image]

Using `ggplot2::geom_raster`

```
DT <- as.data.frame(ExampleMap2, xy = TRUE)

ggplot2::ggplot() + 
  ggplot2::geom_raster(aes(x = x, y = y, fill = as.numeric(as.character(ExampleMap1))), data = DT) + 
  ggplot2::theme_void() +
  ggplot2::scale_fill_continuous(na.value = NA) + 
  guides(fill = guide_legend(NULL)) + 
  coord_equal() +
  theme(aspect.ratio = 1) + 
  labs(title = "ggplot2::geom_raster")
```

[image]

Using `ggplot2::geom_tile` [this seems to work as expected]

```
ggplot2::ggplot() + 
  ggplot2::geom_tile(aes(x = x, y = y, fill = as.numeric(as.character(ExampleMap1))), data = DT) + 
  ggplot2::theme_void() +
  ggplot2::scale_fill_continuous(na.value = NA) + 
  guides(fill = guide_legend(NULL)) + 
  coord_equal() + 
  labs(title = "ggplot2::geom_tile")
```

[image]

What is the reason for this distortion and how to ensure that this does not happen using e.g. `tidyterra::geom_spatraster` or `ggplot2::geom_raster`?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I modified my original answer, noted now under **Old Answer***

It seems to be related with how ggplot handles `NA` on `geom_raster()` when there are few values left (see https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/5523 and https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/3025. Instead use `na.value = "transparent"`

```r
# Get the data

tmp <- "ExampleMap.zip"
download.file(
  "https://github.com/dieghernan/tidyterra/files/13322139/ExampleMap.zip",
  tmp
  
)
dataset <- unzip(tmp, list = TRUE)[1]
unzip(tmp)


load("ExampleMap.RData")

library(terra)
#> terra 1.7.55
library(raster) # For the reprex
#> Loading required package: sp
library(tidyterra)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'tidyterra'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:raster':
#> 
#>     select
#> The following object is masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter
library(ggplot2)
library(paletteer)

ExampleMap2 <- rast(ExampleMap[[2]])

# Delete some extra cells for clarity
smp <- ExampleMap2 %>%
  slice(380000:400000, .keep_extent = FALSE) %>%
  trim()


# Use transparent instead of NA

ggplot() +
  geom_spatraster(data = smp) +
  paletteer::scale_fill_paletteer_c(na.value = "transparent", "viridis::plasma")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-11-15 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

### Old answer

I added several tests to `tidyterra` and didn't find an issue with this. I think here the problem is not that `tidyterra` is distorting the cells, but **how the `ggplot2` palette is filling the plot**, and related with the value of `na.value` of the fill scale.

Maybe this can be an issue on `ggplot2`?

See how the `ggplot2` is affected by this parameter, and a workaround using the `geom_tile()` approach:

```r
# Get the data

tmp <- tempfile(fileext = ".zip")
download.file(
  "https://github.com/dieghernan/tidyterra/files/13322139/ExampleMap.zip",
  tmp
)
dataset <- unzip(tmp, list = TRUE)[1]
unzip(tmp, exdir = tempdir())

library(raster)

## Loading required package: sp

load(file.path(tempdir(), dataset))

library(terra)

## terra 1.7.55

library(tidyterra)
library(ggplot2)
library(paletteer)

ExampleMap2 <- rast(ExampleMap[[2]])

# Delete some extra cells for clarity
as_tibble(ExampleMap2, cells = TRUE, na.rm = TRUE)

## # A tibble: 7 × 2
##     cell ExampleMap2
##    <int>       <dbl>
## 1 281039           1
## 2 343040           1
## 3 389362           1
## 4 391042           1
## 5 392722           1
## 6 392725           1
## 7 435454           1

smp <- ExampleMap2 %>%
  slice(380000:400000, .keep_extent = FALSE) %>%
  trim()

# With terra
plot(smp)
```

[image]

```r
# With tidyterra, no palettes

p <- ggplot() +
  geom_spatraster(data = smp)

# No distortion
p
```

[image]

```r
# When I add the palette
p +
  paletteer::scale_fill_paletteer_c(na.value = NA, "viridis::plasma")
```

[image]

The problem is the na.value param

```r
p +
  paletteer::scale_fill_paletteer_c(na.value = "grey80", "viridis::plasma")
```

[image]

```r
# Full script

ExampleMap1 <- rast(ExampleMap[[1]]) %>% trim()
p2 <- ggplot() +
  geom_spatraster(data = ExampleMap1, maxcell = Inf)

p2 +
  paletteer::scale_fill_paletteer_c(na.value = NA, "viridis::plasma")
```

[image]

```r
# But
p2 +
  paletteer::scale_fill_paletteer_c(na.value = "grey99", "viridis::plasma")
```

[image]

#### Workaround

```r
ExampleMap1 <- rast(ExampleMap[[1]]) %>% trim()

# Make use of the fortify property to pass to geom_tile
ggplot(ExampleMap1, aes(x,y)) +
    geom_tile(aes(fill=ExampleMap1)) +
# Palette
    paletteer::scale_fill_paletteer_c(na.value = NA, "viridis::plasma") +
# Add spatial features to the plot
    coord_sf(crs=terra::crs(ExampleMap1)) +
    labs(x="", y = "")
```

[image]

Comment: I created an issue, see https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/5523

Comment: Updated, use `transparent` in the scale